# What does increasing my Faith/Evil do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Many items, like the Rosary or Ceremonial Robes both say Faith/Evil up (Rosary is faith, Ceremonial Robes is Evil). What does that translate to in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They affect the appearance likelihoods of Devil and Angel Room after defeating a Boss. I'm pretty sure that **Faith** is the opposite of **Evil**/**Sin**.

According to the Wiki, the **Evil** stat increases the chance of the following appearing:
- *Devil Room*
- *Black hearts*

and decreases the chance of the following appearing:
- *Angel Room*
- *Soul hearts*

**Faith** also increases the chance of *The Bible* appearing in the shop.